# I have an Excel sheet that uses many form checkboxes. Is there a way to deselect all checkboxes at once?

Tags: excel, checkbox, vba

I have an Excel document with 62 sheets. Each sheet has numerous form control checkboxes. Is there a way to clear these checkboxes all at once?

Comment: Yes there is. But could you show what have you tried till now?

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChkBoxes()

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim Cb As CheckBox

For Each Sht In Worksheets '<-- loop through all worksheets
    For Each Cb In Sht.CheckBoxes '<-- loop through all checkboxes in sheet
        Cb.Value = False
    Next Cb
Next Sht

End Sub
```